# Create a database table from a Type. In code. Simply

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, orm

I've been looking to replace `SqlCommand`'s with **Entity framework** or **Linq-To-SQL**. However, they seem to rely heavily on using the designer (which I rather minimize), and in the case of Linq-To-SQL it also seems that any change to the database is difficult to change in code.

**So my question is:** Is there any way (presumably using one of the abovementioned technologies) where I can:

1. Create a class.
2. Create a table of it in a database.
3. And bind the class to the database.

If it involves jumping through hoops - never mind. I'm looking to *simplify* my work, not convolute it.

Comment: Sounds **exactly** like what Entity Framework with a **code-first** approach is doing ...

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj193542

Comment: @ken2k Thanks. I'm looking at it now. It seems that I have to download `Entity Framework` - So if it's not included in .net - can I redistribute it?

Comment: @marc_s Thanks. a) For some reason even when checking that out (before posting the question) it seemed I'd still need to rely on the designer. I'm checking it out now again. but: b) will I be able to change a table if my Type changes, or just start from scratch creating a new table?

Comment: With code-first, you have **no designer** - just code. And yes - with the *Migrations* you can easily evolve your database schema - no more *drop everything and start from scratch* necessary...